# How could Vegeta defeat Hakaishin Toppo so easily?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the previous episode God of Destruction Toppo absolutely destroyed Golden Frieza *(who is supposed to be as powerful as Super Saiyan Blue)* and Android 17. His Hakai was also much more powerful compared to the Sidra's Hakai. Goku even with SSB Kaioken struggled against Sidra's Hakai ball whereas Frieza could easily control it. So Golden Frieza just before the Tournament of Power can be considered as strong as SSB Goku.

Also Vegeta's new found power is not as strong as UI Goku because UI Goku could go toe-to-toe and even gain up on Jiren. So if Vegeta's new found power is considered close to or slightly greater than SSB Kaioken then how did Vegeta manage to defeat Toppo in the very next episode so easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few inaccuracies in your question.

- Firstly, Goku was in his base form when Freiza hit him with the Hakai energy and he didn't turn SSJB or Kaioken. In episode 125, we see the Destruction energy capable of destroying all forms of energy, so it is very likely Goku couldn't turn SSJB while he was stuck inside the energy ball. Freiza, on the other hand, was in his golden form and strong enough to break out of it.
- Based on the fight after, we see SSJB Goku per tournament was on the same level as Golden Freiza. It has to be noted that Goku in his SSJB from grew substantially stronger because of multiple Zenkai boosts.
- UI Goku was fighting against a very suppressed Jiren. UI Goku against Kefla was a lot stronger and she was strong enough to take blows from him(Which remarked by Whis weren't powerful as Goku hadn't mastered the attack portion of UI yet). Current Jiren is using a lot more power than he did then.

Vegeta's new form before his fight with Toppo, was relative in power to SSJB+Kaioken*20 Goku(The stronger SSJB Goku), hence making him a lot stronger than Golden Freiza. Freiza in his golden form is even weaker than characters like Anilaza and Kefla in terms of strength. Toppo in his God of destruction form, was stronger than Kefla who was at that time the third strongest(With 1 being Jiren and 2 being Goku). This is why we see Vegeta overwhelmed by Toppo during the initial stage of his fight. When Vegeta powered up after, he reached a level of strength a lot stronger than Kefla and Toppo but weaker than UI Goku and hence was able to knock out Toppo.

During the fight between Universe 7 vs Anilaza(We see 3 SSJB tier characters (And let us assume Gohan and Android 17 are even SSJB tier which they definitely aren't), so 5 SSJB characters being able to hold their own in a beam struggle with Anilaza. Kaioken * 20 SSJB Goku is the same power multiplied 20 times and UI Goku is immensely stronger compared to Kaioken Goku. Vegeta's form is relative to this(initially) and he was a lot stronger than Freiza when he first fought Toppo which is why he wasn't completely Toyed around with.

Comment: If Goku was in his base form and trying to fight Sidra's Hakai, then what stopped him from going SSB Kaioken? Does Hakai prevent transformations or power boosts?

Comment: Firstly, that wasn't a Hakai from Sidra. He gave a fraction of his energy to the assassin(Who was extremely weak), to use it. A hakai from Sidra would've been a lot more powerful. As for the second part of your question, there are two possibilities. 1. (The very likely scenario)Goku usually has a habit of not taking anything seriously until the very end. He used his base form while fighting with Jiren initially, even Monaka(Goku knew Monaka was stronger). So he was very likely trying to break out in his base form. 2. The Hakai energy prevented Goku from transforming easily.

Answer (score 1):

Sidra seems to be one of the weakest gods of destruction. His kai mentions that it might be not so easy for him to destroy Freezer. Freezer also could handle Sidra's hakai energy ball, and he couldnt with Toppo's hakai. I agree with you that Freezer is in the level of Goku in super saiyan blue because that is mentioned in the series. And I agree that Goku super saiyan blue kaioken and Vegeta ultra super saiyan blue might be in a similar level (though we dont know which kaioken Goku was using, ie, x5, x10, x20, etc.) 17 is close to a super saiyan blue, so for Toppo to overpower Freezer and 17 he has to be more powerful than 2 super saiyan blue. But between the power of 2 super saiyan blue, and the power of 20 super saiyan blue (which might be the power of ultra super saiyan blue Vegeta, since he's similar to Goku who might have been using super saiyan blue kaioken x20) there is a lot of room. So for example, Toppo could have the power of 10 super saiyan blue, and Vegeta still being superior to him having the power of 20 super saiyan blue.

Also, I dont agree Vegeta defeated Toppo easily. He was depleted of energy and some of his attacks failed awfully. Toppo and Vegeta seems to be close in power, personally I think Toppo is close to the power of 20 super saiyan blue since he's close to Vegeta and he's close to Goku who probably was using the super saiyan blue kaioken x20.

Comment: I have to disagree about Sidra being the weakest gods of destruction. The argument for the same is headcanon. In the manga, Sidra was strong enough to block a blast attack from Beerus powerful enough to damage multiple destroyers. Also, Sidra gave a fraction of his energy to an assassin weaker than Yamcha in strength. Sidra isn't as aggressive as a god of destruction and is much more on the softer side which is why the Kaioshin made the statement.